# Xcode 11.6 crashing when running test - missing library

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

I am trying to run some `XCTest`. I am not very familiar with it already. I imported my main module to test some classes. I had to open `xcworkspace`, instead of `xcodeproj` and then it compiled.

However, I am still running into an issue. I am using CocoaPods on `macOS` to add Sparkle, and AppCenter to the App. It works fine in the main application, however when I run my test it crashes with the following message:

```
dyld: warning: could not load inserted library '/Users//Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/.../Frameworks/libXCTestBundleInject.dylib' into hardened process because no suitable image found.

dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Sparkle.framework/Versions/A/Sparkle
```

I tried to import these frameworks, which didn't work either. Am I doing something wrong or missing something maybe in the Build Settings?

I also tried adding them in the `Podfile`, which didn't work either.

That's my Test class:

```
@testable import MyApplication
import XCTest

class MoneyTest: XCTestCase {

    var moneyEUR1 : Money!

    override func setUpWithError() throws {
        // Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class.

        self.moneyEUR1 = Money(number: 1200, currency: "EUR")
    }

    override func tearDownWithError() throws {
        // Put teardown code here. This method is called after the invocation of each test method in the class.
        
        self.moneyEUR1 = nil
    }
```

My Podfile:

```
target 'MyApplication' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  #use_frameworks!

  # Pods for MyApplication

  pod 'AppCenter'
  pod 'Sparkle'

  target 'MyApplication Tests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
    # here I tried to add the pod aswell, which didn't work
    # it should actually inherit? shouldn't it?
  end
    
end
```

I don't know where I have to add my Pods framework to the Test Target.

Comment: Is this specific for Xcode 11.6? Have you tried with other versions of Xcode?

Comment: @CongNguyen Not sure, haven't tried it on a different Xcode version tbh.. I might do it and report back